# All redux-form fields re-rendered after a single field changes

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a redux form which has lots of dynamic fields loaded inside it after making an ajax request to get them using action creators.

when I make any change to any single field, all other fields get re-rendered even if I didn't touch or change them.

Here  is the render method

```
public render(): JSX.Element {
    const props = this.props;
    const { handleSubmit } = props;
    let form: any = null, fields = null;
    fields = props.fields.map(field => {
        switch (field.fieldTypeID) {
            case "1": {
                return <Field 
                key={field.fieldId} 
                id={`f${field.fieldId}`} 
                name={`f${field.fieldId}`} 
                component={RenderField} 
                type="int" 
                validate={field.custom.fieldValidations} 
                >
                {[{ field: field }]}
                </Field>;
            }
            case "2": {
                return <Field 
                key={field.fieldId} 
                id={`f${field.fieldId}`} 
                name={`f${field.fieldId}`} 
                component={RenderField} 
                type="text" 
                validate={field.custom.fieldValidations} 
                >
                {[{ field: field }]}
                </Field>;
            }
            case "3": {
                return <Field 
                key={field.fieldId} 
                id={`f${field.fieldId}`} 
                name={`f${field.fieldId}`} 
                component={RenderField} 
                type="textArea" 
                validate={field.custom.fieldValidations}
                >{[{ field: field }]}
                </Field>;
            }
            default:
                return <div/>;
        }
    });
    form = <form name="frm" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit.bind(this))}>
        {fields}
        <RaisedButton type="submit" primary={true} label="Submit"/>
    </form>;
    return form;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

it turns out this re-rendering for all fields happens as I embed custom extra props inside `Field` as a Child element `{[{ field: field }]}` after removing this child element and append extra props into `props` like `<Field props={...customProps}`. it worked without re-rendering all other fields.